# Get string value from XML to Java source program

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I need to know if there is a way to get `String` type data from `strings.xml` (nested in resource tag)

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">One World</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="productInfo_lanIP">LAN IP Address :\t</string>
</resources>
```

and I need to get `productInfo_lanIP` from this and use it in my `MainActivity.java` to perform insertion of another string into this one.

Note: I am updating the value so I can use it to display it just after through an XML page. And I am using Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the strings like:

```
 String productInfo_lanIP = getString(R.string.productInfo_lanIP);
```

go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: Ok I got it its working but I also need to update this value in the strings.xml file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.productInfo_lanIP);
```

Accept the answer if it helped you :)